# Read only reference variable in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my first question here. If I do anything wrong regarding asking or formatting, please tell me!

My program must play something in a Windows Media Player control, wait until it is done playing, then continue with another item.

Below is the entire function:

```
    public void Play(AxWindowsMediaPlayer player, ref bool audioFileFinished)
    {
        int numberOfIntro = rnd.Next(songIntros.Count); //Randomly select an intro from the list
        string introFilePath = songIntros.ElementAt(numberOfIntro).fullPath;
        player.URL = introFilePath;

        //This task is necessary because the while (!audioFileFinished) will otherwise run in the UI and hang the app.
        Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!audioFileFinished)
            {
            }

            player.URL = fullPath;
        });
    }
```

Of course, Visual Studio complains that I may not use a reference variable in the lambda expression. This is logical, as modifying reference variables in asynchronous tasks would be bad, let's keep it at that.

But, I don't have the need to modify it, as it is modified somewhere else in the program. That's why it is a reference variable.

Is there a way to read this variable in a way that Visual Studio accepts? Maybe make it a read only variable? If so, how?

Thanks in advance,
Liam

Comment: You have is you need to ensure that whatever you're reading from will still exist at any point while the lambda runs. A `ref` can refer to a local variable, so that's why it's forbidden. Instead of passing a `ref` parameter, put that in a field somewhere and use it. Maybe your lambda could even be a method of a class with that field in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my specific case. I made the variable `audioFileFinished` a static one. The method to execute in the task is now located in the same class as `audioFileFinished`. My function now looks like this:

```
    public void Play(AxWindowsMediaPlayer player)
    {
        int numberOfIntro = rnd.Next(songIntros.Count); //Randomly select an intro from the list
        string introFilePath = songIntros.ElementAt(numberOfIntro).fullPath;
        player.URL = introFilePath;

        //This task is necessary because the while (!audioFileFinished) will otherwise run in the UI and hang the app.
        Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Radio.PlayAfterThis(fullPath));
    }
```

And the method in the main class looks like this:

```
    public static void PlayAfterThis(string path)
    {
        while (!audioFileFinished)
        {

        }
        localPlayer.URL = path;
    }
```

The variable now gets initialised as `public static bool audioFileFinished;`

Thanks to @Etienne de Martel for suggesting this:

> Maybe your lambda could even be a method of a class with that field in it.

Comment: One downside of using a static field is that you wouldn't be able to use multiple instances of the class. If `audioFileFinished` is set to true then all instances of the class will see that new value. It's not the end of the world but one day someone might create a second instance of the class and then wonder why it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, with admittedly poor names that you might want to change:

```cs
public class Completion : ICompletionNotification
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }

    public void Complete() => IsCompleted = true;
}

public interface ICompletionNotification
{
    bool IsCompleted { get; }
}
```

Calling code creates a new `Completion`, but your `Play` method takes an argument of type `ICompletionNotification`

```cs
public void Play(AxWindowsMediaPlayer player, ICompletionNotification completion)
```

...and checks its `IsCompleted` property.

That way the caller can create a `Completion` and pass it to the `Play()` method which casts it as `ICompletionNotification`.

```cs
var completion = new Completion();
Play(player, completion);
```

The caller can call `Complete()` to indicate that it's done, but the receiver can't set that property. It can only read it.

---

[`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) and `CancellationTokenSource` work pretty much the same way. As the docs say,

> A CancellationToken enables cooperative cancellation between threads, thread pool work items, or Task objects.

```cs
using CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;

// pass the token to some method, and then when it's done call
source.Cancel();
```

It's the same idea. The creator can cancel it, but it passes the token which can only be used to see if the operation has been canceled.

I didn't initially recommend it because technically you're not "cancelling" anything. But it's the same concept and doesn't require defining a new type. Someone who sees it will understand what you're doing or can look up the existing documentation.

Comment: Interesting approach! In fact, the method is already in a class with an interface (the play method is 'interfaced'), so I could add it to that interface. However, I found another solution marked above. If I run into problems further down the line developing this app regarding my solution, maybe I'll try yours!